# Name of starting positions in another array

Tags: data-structures, naming-conventions, naming, conventions

In my code, a pattern that keeps occurring is the use of prefix sum to place certain elements. 
For example:

```
int data[9] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2};

int start[4] = {0, 3, 5, 9};
```

Here, the 0's starts in data at start[0] = 0. 
The 1's starts in data at start[1] = 3, etc.

Additionally, I can easily find the number of 0's by doing

```
number_of_zeroes = start[1] - start[0]
```

Which would of course be equal to 3. I could do the same for the other elements. The only purpose of the 4th element in start is to keep this consistent for all values.

I have two questions:
Does this kind of setup have a name, and is there a better name for "start"? e.g. offset or outset (if that even makes sense)? I could call it prefix sum, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: This sounds a lot like run-length encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: @Welbog thanks, but the values doesnt necessarily have to be equal, but could be a category or a group, such as compressed sparse row format for graphs.